# Validation Select from Drop Down List

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a range of drop down list in sheet `m_list` at `A2` as the following

```
"abc"
"def"
"ghi"
```

I created the drop down list at `Sheet1` using the code below. These lines of code execute when a button is clicked.

```vb
Dim lastRowNo
lastRowNo = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim id As String
id = "def"
    
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
       Operator:=xlEqual, _
       Formula1:="=m_list!" & Range("A2", "A" & lastRowNo).Address
End With
Range("A1").Value = id
```

At the last line, I am trying to set the drop down list to automatically select `"def"` but the drop down did not select it.
`"def"` is available when manually clicked.

Comment: You are setting V12?

Comment: Sorry, that was typo. It should be `A1`

Comment: don't use implicit referencing of a cell - instead use explicit: e.g. `worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = id`

Comment: @Ike Thank you! That works. I'll remember moving forward to use explicit referencing when dealing with many sheets

Answer (score 1):

### Data Validation List

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyDataValidation()
    
    Const ValInit As String = "def"
    
    Dim ValFormula As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("m_list")
        Dim lRow As Long: lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ValFormula = "='" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("A2", "A" & lRow).Address
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        With .Validation
            .Delete
            .Add xlValidateList, , xlEqual, ValFormula
        End With
        .Value = ValInit
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your solution works too. I might follow yours in the future. For now the answer from comment above suits mine.

Comment: I would recommend you reconsider. It may seem like the code was written in a few minutes, but I assure you I took my time to write it. Every line is in its ideal place. So at least study the tiny little differences like e.g. `ThisWorkbook`, `ValFormula`, the various periods (dots)... BTW, I don't mean to undermine the answer in the comments, it covers the main mistake.